# cannot install discord/opus

Tags: node.js, npm, discord

I'm making discord bot. It work perfectly yeseterday. The bot works and I tried to host it on heroku. Then I found some errors.So, I tried to search the solution online and typed `npm cache clean` and delete the node_modules and package-lock.json as the guy said from the solution post.
Then this error occurs when I try to `npm i`. Other packages installed fine except discord\opus.
And the error log is as below.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\Hein Min Htun\Web Development\discord-music-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\B2HD High End Rigs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=E:\Hein Min Htun\Web Development\discord-music-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\opus.node --module_name=opus --module_path=E:\Hein Min Htun\Web Development\discord-music-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3 --msvs_version=2015' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.4.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.9.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "E:\Hein Min Htun\Web Development\discord-music-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\opus.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.6.0/opus-v0.6.0-node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 403 Forbidden on https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.6.0/opus-v0.6.0-node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for @discordjs/opus@0.6.0 and node@16.9.1 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 403 Forbidden on https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.6.0/opus-v0.6.0-node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.9.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.9.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.2 found at "C:\Python39\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\B2HD High End Rigs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\B2HD High End Rigs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\B2HD High End Rigs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\B2HD High End Rigs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\B2HD High End Rigs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\B2HD High End Rigs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\B2HD High End Rigs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\B2HD High End Rigs\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=E:\\Hein Min Htun\\Web Development\\discord-music-bot\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\opus\\prebuild\\node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\\opus.node" "--module_name=opus" "--module_path=E:\\Hein Min Htun\\Web Development\\discord-music-bot\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\opus\\prebuild\\node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3" "--msvs_version=2015"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\Hein Min Htun\Web Development\discord-music-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.9.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\B2HD High End Rigs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=E:\Hein Min Htun\Web Development\discord-music-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\opus.node --module_name=opus --module_path=E:\Hein Min Htun\Web Development\discord-music-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3 --msvs_version=2015' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (E:\Hein Min Htun\Web Development\discord-music-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:85:20)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\Hein Min Htun\\Web Development\\discord-music-bot\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd E:\Hein Min Htun\Web Development\discord-music-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.9.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.4.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\B2HD High End Rigs\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-21T08_45_15_793Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is said here.

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and I tried `npm install --g --production windows-build-tools`. But this also doesn't work.  Do I need to visual studio to solve that error?